# Using dynamicContent/switchFacet/rendered and the component Tree

Tags: xpages, xpages-extlib, dynamic-content

This is a follow-up to a previous post. I have a navigator that sets a sessionScope that is used to determine which one of several views should be displayed in a panel. The onClick does a partial refresh on panelAll. I created 3 custom controls that do essentially the same thing except one using dynamicContent, one with the switchFacet and a third that uses the rendered property on different panels contained in panelAll. Here are my findings:

1. The dynamicContent only loads the currently visible view into the component tree, but does not seem to respond to an external refresh - used both a partial update of panelAll as well as a full UpDate.
2. both the switchFacet and setting the rendered property work when the sessionScope variable is changed and panelAll is refreshed, except the component tree contains all of the components contained within the panel whether they are visible or not. Using this method with 4 or 5 different views seems to respond fairly quickly and gets the job done  (sort of). But is pretty inefficient and could cause issues with a large number of complex views.

I would really like to use the dynamicContent but need a way to cause it to rebuild from the onClick of the navigator. I'm sure there is a reason why the dynamicContent control will not respond to an external partial refresh, but I suspect there is perhaps a way to force a refresh from outside the dynamicContent Control.

Answer (score 0):

I finally got dynamicContent to work from the Navigator. I added this as the onClick of the navigator:

```
getComponent("dynamicContent1").show(context.getSubmittedValue());
return sessionScope.put("ssSelectedView", context.getSubmittedValue());
```

then do a partial Refresh of the panelAll. Now the component tree only contains the the active view, so it should be be the most efficient as far as that goes.